# Python: no module named 'bottle-websocket' when running an executable made with PyInstaller, including Eel module

Tags: python, electron, pyinstaller, eel

I was playing around with the `eel` module for Python - gives an opportunity to run HTML + CSS/JS with the python functionality.

Made a simple program, tried to make an executable out of it via PyInstaller.
No errors whatsoever, but when running this executable it crashes on the first line - **`import eel`**, telling - **`there is no module called 'bottle-websocket'`**.

I checked `pip`: `eel`, `bottle-websocket` are installed. Can't figure out what's the problem. Attachments:

main.py:

```
import eel
from os import path

eel.init(path.dirname(__file__) + "/web")
eel.start('main.html', block=False)
while True:
   eel.sleep(10)
```

Error: 
[Picture with the error while I try to start the exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1aLB.png)

EDIT: 
[PyInstaller Log](http://rgho.st/download/private/8MfwwpF4W/1fad964ad5943e55a669ab08309b07f4/133469ba74e3412b7e913394ada4ae9db13349be/133469ba74e3412b7e913394ada4ae9db13349be/Attachment.txt)

Comment: Check in which Python version you installed the `bottle-websocket` module...

Comment: Can you run this script without Pyinstaller without any error?

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly without PyInstaller @BenyaminJafari

Comment: @R.García bottle-websocket = 0.2.9; eel = 0.9.10; PyInstaller = 3.4.0; Python = 3.6 32 bit

Comment: Added PyInstaller log, if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also having this same  issue, but I finally fixed it, it was actually very very easy, first of all make sure you are using auto-py-to-exe to package your app.

After inserting necessary  details (script file,, extra files etc), you would see an advanced options tab probably below, click on it to expand it, look for the hidden imports label and insert "bottle-websocket" in the input field representing the hidden imports, that's basically all you need to do

I HOPE THIS HELPS

Comment: Yeah, that will work too. Even easier solution than mine, because it uses GUI app.

Answer (score 0):

Took me the whole day figuring out the solution, but finally, here it is:

1. Copy the plugin.py, server.py files from C:\Users\*YOUR_USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bottle_websocket to C:\Users*YOUR_USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib
2. Make sure you have this line as follows in your *.spec file generated by PyInstaller (FOR PYTHON 3.6 32bit):

   datas=[('C:\Users\*YOUR_USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\eel\eel.js', 'eel'), ('*PATH_TO_YOUR_WEB_FOLDER*', '*YOUR_WEB_FOLDER_NAME*')]
   3)Run this command in cmd:
    **python C:\Users\*YOUR_USERNAME*\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\eel\**main**.py   HERE_SHOULD_BE_THE_PATH_TO_YOUR_WEB_FOLDER**

- this command will get the 'bottle-websocket' work and will make sure that it complies with the web folder and files.